# PWA Angular 7 material icons problem on IOS

Tags: angular, angular-material, progressive-web-apps

I created PWA application with angular 7, angular cli 7+, and keycloak as a user authorization layer. Everything works fine on Android devices but on IOS when the app is installed I cannot see the material icons. I'm using self hosted angular material icons from this link: (https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont), and I configured service worker to cache icons in lazy mode. Icons must be self hosted since app won't have internet connection (local network) Any help would be appreciated. Already lost more than 16h on this problem.

What I noticed is that the IOS Safari has a problem with icons only when the page is requested the first time on that device. Second time icons are visible inside browser, but on other had if the shortcut menu icon is added and the app i started from the home menu icons are not visible.

Is it possible that authorization redirection is a problem? IF not what is the reason for safari icon font loading problem? Why safari is not showing the icons?

When I look at the application/service worker files in google developer tools I can see that the icon font is loaded.

Service worker:
`

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved with keycloak initialisation param.I changed onLoad to login-required. When page starts to load and then is redirected to login, during that process icons starts to load and stop when keycloak angular client redirects to login page. That probably created a problem for safari and somehow safari breaks icons

```
       await keycloak.init({
          config: environment.keycloak,
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            checkLoginIframe: false
          },
          bearerExcludedUrls: []
        });
```